# C# ASP.NET API constructor looping on WIndows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I host my Web API application on Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS Version 7.5), development using .NET Framework 4.8. When I try to make a request, in the class below and perform remote debugging, the process always loops over the constructor without stopping. Its running well on IIS 10.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter()
    {
        ReadAllowedAppsIDFile();
    }
    
    .... etc .....
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you confirm the `Managed pipeline mode` option of your Application Pool set to `Integrated`?

Comment: Are you sure it is looping, or are people/services actively using the application? If you are debugging you will stop on all invocations.

Comment: @WillHuang, Yes I am using Integrated Managed pipeline mode

Comment: @Crowcoder, only use by my self. Yeah its looping, constructor and back to read fields

Comment: @Slocky Can you provide full source code?